# What is the contrapositive of the definition of onto?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, logic, function-and-relation-composition

I feel that the problem I am working on will be easier to prove by contrapositive, namely instead of showing surjective I want to show the contrapositive of surjective.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you write out the definition of "surjective"?  What kind of sentences can you take the contrapositive of?

Comment: For $f:A\rightarrow B$, then a surjections is defined when the following holds: $\forall b\in B \exists a\in A$ s.t. $f(a)=b$

Comment: Perhaps it is $\forall a\in A\exists b\in B$ s.t. $f(a)\neq b$...

Comment: I think you mean _negation_ of surjective.  One proves the contrapositive of a statement, not a definition.  I.e. if you're trying to show "If $P$ then $f$ is surjective", the contrapositive would be "If $f$ is not surjective, then $\neg P$ is true".

Comment: Its the first one, for each $b$ I can find an $a$ such that $f(a) =b$.  But the thing is, as you have written it, there is no implication $(\implies)$ and so it doesn't really make sense to talk about contrapositive. (And I don't think there is a way to write it with an implication).

Comment: That's a *faux pax* on my part, yes. Sorry. Then, I don't know. I mean does "contrapositive of onto" even make sense?

Comment: What is the problem you're working on?  Some context would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The term "contrapositive" refers to a certain formal transformation of *implications*.

Specifically, the contrapositive of
$$p\implies q$$
is
$$\lnot q \implies \lnot p.$$

It doesn't really make sense to ask for the contrapositive of a property like surjectivity.

**Edit:**

The statement "$f\colon A \to B$ is surjective" (when $f$ is known to be a function from $A$ to $B$) can be written
$$(\forall y\in B)(\exists x \in A)\bigl((x,y)\in f\bigr).$$

The *negation* of this statement is $f\colon A \to B$ is *not* surjective.

By the usual laws of predicate logic, this is equivalent to
$$(\exists y\in B)(\forall x \in A)\lnot\bigl((x,y)\in f\bigr).$$

Answer (score 3):

Surjectivity of $f:A\to B$ can be expressed as:

> If $b\in B$, then $\exists a\in A: f(a)=b$.

The contrapositive of this is:

> If $(\forall a\in A: f(a)\neq b)$ then $b\notin B$.

I can't imagine any case where that would be any easier to prove, however.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f:X\to{Y}$ is surjective if:

$$(\forall y)\space(\exists x)\space{f(x)}=y$$

Negating this:

$$\lnot((\forall y)\space(\exists x)\space{f(x)}=y)$$

$$(\exists y)\space\lnot((\exists x)\space{f(x)}=y)$$

$$(\exists y)\space(\forall x)\space{f(x)}\ne{y}$$

Therefore the contrapositive of the standard definition of surjective is:

> If there exists a $y\in{Y}$ such that for all $x\in{X}$ $f(x)\ne{y}$, then $f:X\to{Y}$ is **not** surjective.

Answer (score 0):

What you're (probably) looking for is the *negation* of the definition of surjective.  To find the negation, remember that "for alls become there exists" and "there exists become for alls".  So,

$$
\neg (\forall b\in B\exists a\in A: f(a)=b)\quad\text{is}\quad  (\exists b\in B:\forall a\in A, f(a)\neq b)
$$  Try to *really think* about what surjective means though, and what it would mean to not be that.  Drawing pictures always helps!